# regex for dynamic content of with variable "parts"

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to handle input that may be variable length with one regex expression?

e.g., the string may be "a < b or b < c or c > d" and I'd want to convert it to "(a < b) OR (b < c) OR (c > d)"

or the string may be "a = b and c = d", in which case I'd want to convert it to "(a = b) AND (c = d)"

Comment: The variable length is not an issue, but what is the issue, is that you cannot make two replacements with one expression - make "or"/"and" uppercase and place brackets around comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
([a-z]\s*[<|>|=]\s*[a-z])
```

and then replace group with `($1)`.

You may have to perform additional replace-all function to change all small `or/and` to capital.

Comment: actually it's a bit more complicated than my examples, e.g., "street IS NOT NULL or city IS NOT NULL or state IS NOT NULL" and "flag in ('Y', 'N') and flag is not null"

Comment: @wlaem so basically it can be `anything and anything or anything ...`

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example where only one regex is used.**

The regex used is **"\s+(or|and)\s+"**, see below.

**"a < b or b < c or c > d"** example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputOr = "a < b or b < c or c > d";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\s+(or|and)\\s+").matcher(String.format("(%s)", inputOr));

    if(matcher.find()) {
        String logicalOperatorUpperCase = matcher.group(1).toUpperCase();
        String changedLogicalExpression =  matcher.replaceAll(String.format(") %s (", logicalOperatorUpperCase));
        System.out.println(changedLogicalExpression); // output: '(a < b) OR (b < c) OR (c > d)'
    }
}
```

**"a = b and c = d"** example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputAnd = "a = b and c = d";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\s+(or|and)\\s+").matcher(String.format("(%s)", inputAnd));

    if(matcher.find()) {
        String logicalOperatorUpperCase = matcher.group(1).toUpperCase();
        String changedLogicalExpression =  matcher.replaceAll(String.format(") %s (", logicalOperatorUpperCase));
        System.out.println(changedLogicalExpression); // output: '(a = b) AND (c = d)'
    }
}
```